# Need to disable the range of cells based on the drop down input from another cell

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to lock a particular range of cells based on the input from a dropdown in a row of data?  For example, The row `C5` contains `Yes` or `No`  (which is selected/entered via a dropdown). If I choose `No`, the cells `F11:F28` should be disabled also protect input fields so nothing can be entered.

```
ActiveSheet.Protect Contents:=True
```

after locking cells

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)  
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub  
    Set myRng = Range("F11:F28")  
    For Each C In myRng
        If C.Address = Target.Address And ActiveSheet.Name = ActiveSheet.Range("C5").Value ="Yes" Then
            ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:= "xyz"  
            Range("F11:F28").Locked = False  
            ActiveSheet.Protect Password:= "xyz"  
            Exit For  
        Else  
            ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:= "xyz"  
            Range("F11:F28").Locked = True
            ActiveSheet.Protect Password:= "xyz"  
        End If  
    Next C  
End Sub
```

Expected Results:

When I choose `No` in cell `C5` the cell range from `F11:F28` should be disabled/protected so nothing can be entered.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the `Worksheet_Change`.
2. Define your password as constant so you only have to change it once (in case you need to change it.
3. Use the [Application.Intersect method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.intersect) to check if `Target` and `Me.Range("C5")` intersect (that means C5 was changed).

The followinig should work.

```
Option Explicit

Private Const SHEET_PASSWORD As String = "xyz"

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C5")) Is Nothing Then
        Dim MyRng As Range
        Set MyRng = Me.Range("F11:F28")

        Me.Unprotect Password:=SHEET_PASSWORD

        If Me.Range("C5").Value = "Yes" Then
            MyRng.Locked = False
        Else
            MyRng.Locked = True
        End If

        Me.Protect Password:=SHEET_PASSWORD
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that this is case sensitive. If you want to allow both `Yes` and `yes` then use

```
If LCase(Me.Range("C5").Value) = "yes" Then
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. i'm getting object required error while running the code

Comment: @Anu Sorry forgot to `Dim MyRng As Range`. See edited answer.

Comment: Thank You.. It works fine with in a sheet. how do i disable the range of cells on another sheet ( say Sheet2) based on the value in the current sheet(say Sheet1)

Comment: @Anu the `Worksheet_Change` event needs to be in the sheet where you want to check the value that gets changed (`Sheet1`). And then use something like `Set MyRng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("F11:F28")` to lock the range in another sheet.

Comment: Well then please mark this question as solved and ask a new one (showing your actual code and mention the line where you get the error). This is a new issue now. We cannot answer follow up questions in comments.